# NodeJS DNS error: ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, dns

I get the follwing error: `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`. The URL I am trying to connect to is a subdomain on HTTPS.

```
var options = 
    {
        family: 4,
        hostname: 'test.printapi.nl',
        port: 443,
        path: '/v1/oauth',
        method: 'POST',
        requestCert: true,
        headers: {
            host: 'https://test.printapi.nl',
            //'User-Agent': USER_AGENT,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
        }
    };
    options.agent = http.Agent(options);

    var req = http.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log('statusCode: ', res.statusCode);
      console.log('headers: ', res.headers);

      res.on('data', (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
      });
    }, data);
    console.log(data)
    req.write(data)
    req.end();

    req.on('error',function(e){
   console.log("Error: "  + e.message); 
   console.log( e.stack );
});
```

I have tried many things, with the path, hostname etc. When I use fiddler I need to set a proxy, and fiddler will resolve the hostname of test.printapi.nl, and it will authenticate. But when node needs to do it, it does not find the right DNS record.

I have tried `dns.getServers()`, and it did return the correct DNS server. I also tried the google DNS servers, and that did not help. Am I overlooking something I need to set for the hostname to resolve?

--EDIT
If I use https I get `cannot read property 'maxCachedSessions'`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ENOTFOUND` means no DNS entry was found for the `hostname`. The problem in this case is that the `hostname` should *not* include the *path*. Instead it should look like:

```
var options = {
  hostname: 'test.printapi.nl',
  path: '/v1/oauth'
  // ...
```

Also, you don't need to explicitly set the `Host` header. The `port` number disagrees with the module you're using -- if it's an https connection, use `https.request()` instead of `http.request()`.

Lastly, you can either remove or will need to change this line:

```
options.agent = http.Agent(options);
```

to this:

```
options.agent = new https.Agent(options);
```

Comment: If I use the https module, a whole other set of problems apear, that do not apear with http... If I use https I get `cannot read property 'maxCachedSessions'` of undefined. The above mentioned error does not change with using path or not, but I will change my code example, it will be more clear like that. I also will post the reason why I do not use https with the question, to avoid future inquiries.

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: I have tried 4.4.2 and now I am running 5.10.1, so the LTS and stable that are th most recent.

Comment: I've updated my answer which should solve that particular error.

Comment: That has solved the problem indeed, and I now get my authentication :)